# React Native App renders nothing without errors

Tags: android, react-native, android-virtual-device

I am building react native app and when I run it on android it renders nothing, as well it doesn't throw any errors...

I don't know which piece of code to put here so please tell me in the comments what should I add from the code here.

This is App.js file(react-native-navigation is being used here!):

```
Navigation.startTabBasedApp({
  tabs:[
      {
        screen:"APB.ChoosePlatformScreen",
        label: "Log In",
        title:"Log In",
        icon: HomeIcon,
      },
      {
        screen: "APB.ResgisterScreen",
        label: "Register",
        title:"Register",
        icon: HomeIcon
      },
],
appStyle: {
  tabBarBackgroundColor: "#e8e8e8",
  tabBarButtonColor: "#555",
  tabBarSelectedButtonColor: 'black',
  tabBarSelectedBackgroundColor: "#e8e8e8",
  forceTitlesDisplay: true,
  showLabel: true,
},
tabBarOptions: {
  showLabel: true
}  
})
```

Above all of this are all the file imports an all screens are registered, I didn't put it in so the code is not too long.

Comment: Can you show the App.js file? Especially the render function.

Comment: I updated the question.

Comment: Unfortunately, I never used startTabBasedApp to give a real answer, but according to https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/top-level-api?id=starttabbasedappparams you need to register the screens first. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes they are all registered. I just didn't put it in the code above so the question is not too long.

Comment: How do you exporting your app js content ?

Comment: When index.android.js calls App.js it runs this function .startTabBasedApp() and then it should run the first screen provided which in this case is APB.ChoosePlatformsScreen

Comment: In rendering the screen did you return the components?

Comment: You mean if I did export default?